# How can I return a tuple with multiple fields from Combiner/Reducer/Aggregator function?

Tags: apache, spring-boot, apache-storm, trident, apache-storm-topology

[Here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/Trident-API-Overview.html) Storm Documentation states: 
*A CombinerAggregator returns a single tuple with a single field as output.*

What should I do to return a tuple with multiple fields from Combiner function?

I am creating a aggregate function and want to aggregate two or more values from the input tuple and send these two or more fields as output.

I also want to have some fields of the input tuple in output.
How can I use Combiner Function to get the required output?

Input Tuple to Combiner Aggregator function:

`("a", "b", "c" , "d")`

Required Output Tuple:

`("a", "b", "newValue1", "newValue2", "newValue3")`

In the past, I tried creating a model in the `init()` method of CombinerAggregator from the fields of the tuple and returning it from the CombinerAggregator as a output. But I don't feel that's the right solution.
Does `chainedAgg()` function works well with this kind of situation?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to use the more general `Aggregator` interface.

From the link you posted:

> The most general interface for performing aggregations is Aggregator, which looks like this:

```
public interface Aggregator<T> extends Operation {
    T init(Object batchId, TridentCollector collector);
    void aggregate(T state, TridentTuple tuple, TridentCollector collector);
    void complete(T state, TridentCollector collector);
}
```

> Aggregators can emit any number of tuples with any number of fields.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I've tried it. But I've question. Does it depend on the type of Spout being used in topology? Currently, The topology uses IRichSpout.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not very familiar with using Trident with regular non-batch spouts.

Comment: The problem occured by using Aggregator Function with IRichSpout is : the aggregated value resets every time a new event is consumed from kafka topic instead of adding it up. I'm really not sure whether this problem is with spout(depending on the way tuples are sent from spout) or something else.

Comment: Consider raising an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira. If you can make a small reproduction showing the issue (e.g. a small project on github or similar), we can probably figure out whether it's a bug or misconfiguration.